# Creating a Directory with MkDir then appending the Folder to a Html doc?

Tags: php, javascript, html, append, mkdir

I have an A-Z list of users, and I'd like to be able to append the new folders created with `mkdir()` instead of manually adding them to the .html page. Just attached an example

Eg:

```
UserList.html
Example user:
<a href="Obama/"><font size="4" color="yellow">Barrack Obama</a>

Mkdir Form:

<form action="Create.php" method="post">
Full Name: <input type="text" name="Username" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Create User Folder"/>
</form>

Create.php
<?php
mkdir($_POST["UserName"], 0777);
?>
```

Comment: To clarify: Do you want the links to update as you add more users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NB: Suggest making these folders in a different directory then your root directory, maybe users/obama**

You could use a function called readdir() which will read the contents of the directory ready for output.

http://au.php.net/readdir

Here is a link to some information about reading dir's in php

[http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/13426-list-of-folders/page_*view*_findpost_*p*_134369](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/13426-list-of-folders/page__view__findpost__p__134369)

Answer (score 0):

have another request that returns all the folders in the user directory and put them on the page. i.e create the link html in php as well. you could use ajax if you want to do this without reloading the page.